# What is the relationship between sorted and lambda

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

Can someone help me to understand this code please:

```
tuple1 = (('a', 23), ('b', 37), ('c', 11), ('d', 29))
tuple1 = tuple(sorted(list(tuple1), key=lambda x: x[1]))
print(tuple1)
```

Comment: Check out sort documentation: [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: The `key` tells `sorted()` what criteria to sort the thing on. So instead of sorting it on the entire element, it now sorts it on just the second subelement.

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted/). `key` is just a lambda of method that is used to extract the key to use for sorting. In your example, you are sorting `tuple1` based on the value of the second value in each sub tuple so it should end up as `(('c', 11), ('a', 23), ('d', 29), ('b', 37))`

Comment: But, how lambda can define the criteria? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`sorted` is a function which can sort a list according to some criteria. The criteria can be customized by passing a function as the `key` parameter.

`lambda` is a way to define a function. So it can be used to specify the criteria for sorting.

Comment: But, how lambda can define the criteria? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the docs for [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

> *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in *iterable* (for example, key=str.lower). The default value is None (compare the elements directly).